# webpack: Tether is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, tether

I'm creating a WebExtension, I need to use the selection-menu library in my content.js. It has in tether dependencies, so I installed:

```
npm install tether
npm install selection-menu
```

Then in my code I write:

```
import * as Tether from 'tether'
import SelectionMenu from 'selection-menu'

...
    this.selection_menu = new SelectionMenu({
      container: document.body,
      content: '<button> click me </button>',
      onselect: function(e) {
        this.menu.innerHTML = 'Selection length: ' + this.selectedText.length;
      }
    });
```

but when I select text, I get an error:

```
VM1492:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: Tether is not defined
    at i.show (<anonymous>:23:2899)
    at <anonymous>:23:4192
```

but in the page code I see that tether was imported[image: screen]

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me:

in my webpack.config.js:

```
config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    tether: 'tether',
    Tether: 'tether',
    'window.Tether': 'tether',
  })
]);
```